# Service/scheduler to compile and deploy a .net project

Tags: .net, compilation

I need to create Service/scheduler to compile and deploy a different .net projects.
I have been looking at various tools like Cruisecontrol, Octopus, Puppet etc.
Can somebody please suggest which one is the best and easy to user with multiple .net projects of possibly different version with minimal change in the projects itself.
Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

After much research, CruiseControl has turned out to be the best option. As I required minimal change to code. I worked with writing Nant scripts and running the same through CruiseControl by scheduling the time.